# Check if a sentence includes any words in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
splitDescription = work.workdescription.downcase.split(' ')

keywords = ['teamwork', 'developed', 'enhanced', 'transformed', 'achieved','grew', 'introduced', 'project', 'awarded',
             'planned','supervised','created','designed','discovered','evaluated','promoted','represented','completed',
             'devised','liaised','controlled','researched','organised','achieved','managed','analysed','assessed','conducted',
             'solved','responsible for','responsibilities']

splitDescription.select {|word| word.include?(keywords)}.each do |word|
    new_score += 0.5
end
```

I have a `splitDescription` which splits and store a description.

I want to see if any of the keywords are in the `splitDescription` and for each `keyword` in the `splitDescription` the `new_score` goes up by 0.5.

Im trying this code at the moment but it does not work correctly.

Comment: You probably want to use `.split`, rather than `split(' ')`, as the former is equivalent to `.split(/\s+/)`, which swallows extra spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
splitDescription.select { |word| keywords.include?(word) }
```

since here `keywords` are an array to lookup the single `word` in.

More robust solution would be:

```
new_score += 0.5 * (splitDescription & keywords).size
```

The latter will intersect the `keywords` array and splitted description, calculates the size of intersection and increase the score by this value divided by two.

Comment: I recommend the solution with intersection too.

Comment: I think i did not put the question write, but for each word found the score should go up by 0.5 so if there are 5 words found in splitDescription then then total score should go up to 2.5 @mudasobwa

Comment: @mudasobwa Iv tried this but it does not seem to work

Comment: Of course it works and you might see this by count of upvotes. I suspect you are not aware of that e.g. `'responsible for'` keyword is never matched because the description was splitted by space and/or you did not initialize `new_score` in advance, or you did not read and applied Cary’s comment or smth else outside of this snippet. The code above, though, works like a charm.